# I have a problem with importing a dataset in R

Tags: r, import, data-science

I'm a beginner wih R, and I don't understand why the program gives me error. This is my code:

```
my_dir <- 'C:/DATI/MARTA/UNIPV/Data Science/exchanges(2)'
```

This is the error:

```
Warning messages:
In read.table(path, encoding = encoding, header = header, sep = sep,  :
incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/Users/Marta/Desktop/MARTA (DATI).lnk'
```

Then I tried to run the read_excel function and gives me again an error. This is my code:

```
exchanges <- read_excel(my_dir, "exchanges.xlxs", sep='')
```

This is the error:

```
Error in read_excel(my_dir, "exchanges.xlxs", sep = "") : 
unused argument (sep = "")
```

Can someone help me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at this tutorial: https://statisticsglobe.com/warning-in-read-table-incomplete-final-line-found-in-r It explains why the "incomplete final line found" warning message appears and how to fix it.